# Visual Studio load test error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, controller, load-testing, agent

I am using visual studio 2013 loadtest and I have a weird problem. I have 5 agents and 1 controller. After about a day of testing, there is always a socket exception in some of the agents. I can live with a simple disconnect after a day, but instead of disconnecting the tests continue but don't run my plugin anymore causing the load test to have no worth. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the exception text and give context? In particular, I want to know whether the socket connection is between the controller attempting to talk to its agents (what I inferred) or whether the socket exception is thrown by the application in response to test requests.

Comment: Doe the socket exceptions happen at a particular time? Do your event logs on your computer show any correlated events that could be potential causes of disruption?